# Why output keeps same many output?

Tags: java

```
boolean yn = true;
        while(yn)
        {
            System.out.println("please enter your name");
            char name = (char) System.in.read();
            switch(name)
            {
                case 'y':
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 'Y':
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 'N':
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("You did not input a correct choice");
            }
```

When I enter other keys than `y` or `n`, more than one of same output keeps coming out. Any suggestions? I want to see only one output, and `System.in.read()` is a must. Not scanner.

Comment: when you enter `y` or `n` then default wont be executed, i guess you know that.

Comment: when I enter 'b', the output displays same words 3 times. any suggestion  please? I want to see only one output...

Comment: @JamesGuy what output?

Comment: Is this the end of the code block? Post a MVCE

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31644431/9218757) and [this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255685/9218757) may help you

Comment: Yes, [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: question is good btw.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `System.in.read()` to read in the next character, but when you type a character and hit enter, you're actually entering *three* characters: The character you typed, a carriage return character ('\r'), and a newline character ('\n').  I assume you're on a Mac, because Windows machine just use the newline character.

Since you're inside of a `while` loop, it keeps reading until you hit a valid character that sets `yn` to `true`.

You might consider using a `Scanner` to make this easier.

Comment: I think you're right.  This is his problem....the newline character(s).  I'll just point out, however, that Mac acts just like Linux, and uses only '\n' as EOL.  I thought it was just Windows that used '\r\n' for EOLs. - but this only matters in that he might get two extra characters he might not expect rather than 1.

Comment: I tested locally and saw just '\n' on my Windows machine, so I assumed it was "\r\n" on Linux-based systems.  I wonder if it's just an IntelliJ console thing.

Comment: It may be that System.in is opened in "character mode", like doing open("xxx", "r") rather than open("xxx", "rb").  In the former case, Java standardizes the stream on all systems to only return '\n'.  Only if you're reading in "binary mode" do you possibly get something other than '\n'.  The one way I'm pretty sure you get "\r\n" is if you open a Windows file in "rb" mode. - I bet you always get just '\n' from System.in.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of infinite loop is you read input from `System.in.read()` and cast it into `char`.

`System.in.read()` will return code `-1` when the end of input stream. If you cast it into `char` the value will be `65535`.

So, please add this piece of code after:
`char name = (char) System.in.read();`

```java
System.out.println("name="+name);
char next = (char)System.in.read();
if(next==65535)
    break;
```

This code works for me.
https://ideone.com/ppk3Fi

Comment: Huh?  How does System.in.read() every get to "the end of input stream"?  That's relevant for files, but not standard input.

Comment: @Steve 
according to [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) the read() method will return -1 when the end of stream is reached.

Comment: I understand that.  But what does "the end of stream is reached" mean for System.in?  One does not normally reach EOS for System.in.  It provides characters or blocks forever.

Comment: Oh, I get your point. The input stream will not be empty, so `read()` method must always provide bytes to return. In openJDK implementation, if you did not set `InputStream in System.in`, it will default use BufferedInputStream. The BufferedInputStream override [read](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedInputStream.java#l263) method, it will return `-1` when the buffer is empty.

Comment: @Steve I would like to know the reason of input stream must not be empty. Could you please give some document to read or any keyword??

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on this.
Using Scanner class instead.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("please enter your name");
char name = scanner.next().charAt(0);
```

Mine I would get the first character entered instead.